# Deleting leaves from a binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

```
public void deleteLeaves(BSTNode<T> p){                     //deletes leaves
    if(p.left != null){
      if(isLeaf(p.left))
        p.left = null;
    }
    else if(p.right != null){
      if(isLeaf(p.right))
        p.right = null;
    }
    else{
      deleteLeaves(p.right);
      deleteLeaves(p.left); 
    }
  }
```

I cannot seem to figure out as to why it is not correctly deleting the leaves. It seems to only delete the final leaf of the tree. Any advice that helps would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if-statements are a bit messed up; Only *one* of the branches will be taken. Think about what should happen if neighter `p.left` nor `p.right` is null.

If I understand your data structure correctly, I'd probably write it like this:

```
// If there is something to the left...
if (p.left != null)
    if (isLeaf(p.left))
        p.left = null;             // delete it if it's a leaf...
    else
        deleteLeaves(p.left);      // else recurse.

// If there's something to the right...
if (p.right != null)
    if (isLeaf(p.right))
        p.right = null;            // delete it if it's a leaf...
    else
        deleteLeaves(p.right);     // else recurse.
```

Comment: This answer solved a problem I had for the same issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28313390/removing-leaves-from-binary-tree-not-being-represented-properly/28313612#28313612

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, if `p.left != null` then it won't even check for `p.right`. The `else-if` should just be an `if`. Also, you're saying if both neighboring nodes are null, then call `deleteLeaves()` on them, which makes no sense cuz they're null. Restructure your code; @aioobe has a good suggestion

Answer (score 0):

To use recursion properly, it must be in the same kind of control statement. You shouldn't check the condition in an if, and then do the actual recursion in an else if or else.

Comment: I see no problem in recursing inside a conditional block.

Comment: Appologies if it was read as such, what I meant was that the recursion should be done in the same conditional block that determines if recursion is needed/how it is implemented.