# Removing leaves from Binary Tree not being represented properly

Tags: java, binary-tree

I have been working on creating a Binary Tree from scratch, not using built-in libraries. I am working on a function called "pruneLeaves". The job is to remove all leaves of the tree; nodes with no children.

When I step through the function with breakpoints, it appears to be removing the leaves and even prints out that it is indeed removing the proper nodes. However, when I display the tree in my main function afterwards, the nodes are still there!

I have tried for hours to figure this out, what am I overlooking?!

Program Output:

```
Num nodes = 9
Pruning.
12
Leaf removed
9
Leaf removed
4
Leaf removed
Tree after pruning..
3 4 5 6 7 8 9 11 12
```

---

```
    // Recursive helper. Accepts BinaryNode as a parameter
private BinaryNode pruneLeaves(BinaryNode t) {

    // If we have no left child AND no right child, we are a leaf
    if ((t.left == null) && (t.right == null)) {

        //Print the element being removed.
        System.out.println (t.element);

        //Remove the element
        t = remove(t.element, t);

        if(t == null)
            System.out.println("Leaf removed");
    }
    // Else we have at least one child
    else {

        if (t.right != null) {
            pruneLeaves(t.right);
        }

        if (t.left != null) {
            pruneLeaves(t.left);
        }
    }
  //Return our leafless tree
  return t;
}

// Main recursive method, call the helper method by passing the root of the 
// tree, which calls it.
public void pruneLeaves () {
    pruneLeaves(this.getRoot());
}

BinaryNode getRoot () {
    return this.root;
}

/**
 * Internal method to remove from a subtree.
 * @param x the item to remove.
 * @param t the node that roots the tree.
 * @return the new root.
 */
private BinaryNode remove( int x, BinaryNode t )  {
success = false;
    if( t == null )
        return t;   // Item not found; do nothing

    if( x < t.element )
        t.left = remove( x, t.left );

    else if( x > t.element )
        t.right = remove( x, t.right );

    else {
        success = true;

        if( t.left != null && t.right != null )  { // Two children
            t.element = findMin( t.right ).element;
            t.right = remove( t.element, t.right );
        }

        else
        t = ( t.left != null ) ? t.left : t.right;
    }
    return t;
}
```

And my main method, calling the function:

```
    public static void main( String [ ] args )   {
    BST t = new BST( );

    t.insert(7);
    t.insert(6);
    t.insert(5);
    t.insert(3);
    t.insert(4);
    t.insert(8);
    t.insert(11);
    t.insert(9);
    t.insert(12);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println ("Num nodes = " + t.countNodes());
    System.out.println ("Pruning.");

    // Remove leaves of the tree
    t.pruneLeaves();
    t.infix();
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: What's the content of the remove() method?

Comment: The way I'm looking at it the whole remove function is pointless. Your calling remove with arguments t.element and t. So your if statements that compare t.element to x will always fall to the last else statement. Your t.left and t.right are always going to be null so your remove will always just return null. So this changes the question to "why is setting t = null not changing the BST?"

Comment: @BoldAsLove, you are exactly right. It was a pointless call and after searching a bit more on the site, I found an answer that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the link: [Deleting Leaves From a Binary Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839664/deleting-leaves-from-a-binary-tree?rq=1)

I have found the errors in my code and corrected them using the answer given in the link.

Correct Code as follows:

```
private BinaryNode pruneLeaves (BinaryNode p) {

    // There is a left child
    if (p.left != null)
        if (isLeaf(p.left)) //Is that child a leaf?
            p.left = null;             
        else
            pruneLeaves(p.left);      // If it is not, recursive call

    // Is there a right child
    if (p.right != null)
        if (isLeaf(p.right))
            p.right = null;            
        else
            pruneLeaves(p.right);     // Recursive call
    return p;
}

// Main recursive call, passes the root of calling tree to the helper method
public void pruneLeaves () {
    pruneLeaves (this.getRoot());
}

// Returns true if child is a leaf
boolean isLeaf (BinaryNode t) {
    if (t.left == null && t.right == null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is the answer, but IMO its important to note that the reason your method didn't work is due to a misunderstanding of what you were setting to null. You were setting a reference to null, not the actual node.

Comment: But if I remoe the references to the node, won't it be picked up by garbage collection?

Comment: Yes, if you remove the reference to the node in the _parent_ node and no other references exist, then it will be picked up. What that method was doing was setting the local reference to null, which did not affect the reference in the parents node at all. The fix posted above now sets the reference in the parent node to null, which is correct.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for being right answer (only one I've found so far), but you forgot the null scenario for the root, and also to remove the root if the root itself has no children. Here's how I did it - I used your code and then made sure it fit all scenarios:

```
public void removeLeaves () {
    if (root != null) {
        removeLeaves (root);
    } else {
        return;
    }
}

private Node removeLeaves (Node node) {
    if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {
        root = null;
    } else {
        if (node.left != null) {
            if (node.left.left == null && node.left.right == null) {
                node.left = null;             
            } else {
                removeLeaves(node.left);
            }
        }
        if (node.right != null) {
            if (node.right.left == null && node.right.right == null) {
                node.right = null;      
            } else {
                removeLeaves(node.right);     
            }
        }
    }
    return node;
}
```

This code ensures that all nodes with no children are removed, and also eliminates the need for the isLeaf() function.

Comment: Thanks for the update and the fixes for the answer! I appreciate you taking the time and effort to post on this! I'll update my old code :)